# Re-defining `\\`

Tags: macros, hooks

EDIT:  The original version of this was a foolish question; @egreg [points out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/536017) that I was thinking of `{amsmath}`'s matrix environment.

I'm sure that this has been asked before, but it's hard to search for `\\`.  I would like to add a hook to modify the behaviour of the `\\` line-breaking command, but my naïve approach didn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\[\def\\{\end{matrix}, \begin{matrix}}
\begin{matrix}
a \\ c
\end{matrix}\]
\end{document}
```

My desired output is the same as if I had typed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix}
a \end{matrix}, \begin{matrix}c
\end{matrix}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: To see how it's defined, you can use `latexdef '\\'` --- be prepared for a surprise... ;-)

Comment: Please first explain why you want to achieve in the end rather than trying to mess with stuff one really should not be messing with

Comment: @Rmano, I am not surprised, in the sense that I expected a complicated definition.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to use the definition I see to understand what's happening.

Comment: @daleif, what I want to achieve is to change the behaviour of the `\\\`.  It's totally fair to say "you shouldn't", and it sure seems like that's your answer; but it still doesn't answer the question for me of what's going on here, which is interesting to me even if, in learning it, I am also given enough wisdom not to do it.

Comment: It is not the `amsart` class involved, but the `amsmath` package (which is automatically loaded by `amsart`). It would be more useful to know *what* your redefined ``\\`` is supposed to do; surely not printing a “b”.

Comment: @egreg, I thought it was best to stick to why re-defining `\\\` was a problem at all before getting into my specific re-definition—but the problem was my own foolishness, as you pointed out (more politely).  I have given my actual application.  (Also, how do you get the double backslash escaped?  The obvious-to-me thing, surrounding it with backticks, doesn't work, and neither does triple or quadruple backslashes.)

Comment: @LSpice -- Ignoring the actual question, but giving the formula for typing a double backslash in a comment: type a backtick, then two backslashes, then a space (spacebar), then the closing backtick.  Result: `\\ `.   (Notice the extra space that follows the backslashes.)  There's a post somewhere on meta (maybe the "main" meta, I don't remember) that explains it.

Comment: Since you're replacing `\\ ` completely (instead of adding a hook), why not just use some other command?  `\def\newmatrix{\end{matrix},\begin{matrix}}` would have the same result, and not try to redefine a low level command.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's what I've used as well. But egreg somehow did it without the extra space.  Maybe that comes once you hit 6 figure rep on the site ;)

Comment: @Teepeemm, fair [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536007/re-defining#comment1354548_536007).  I wanted to typeset a matrix, and then I wanted to typeset the list of its rows, and I didn't want to have to re-type the matrix the second time and make a bunch of fiddly changes.  Anyway, I expect re-defining low-level commands to break things, but not just to be ignored, which is what appears to happen in my code sample.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `matrix` environment in the LaTeX kernel.

```latex
\DeclareRobustCommand\matrix[1]{\null\,\vcenter{\normalbaselines\m@th
    \ialign{\hfil$##$\hfil&&\quad\hfil$##$\hfil\crcr
      \mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}
      #1\crcr\mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}}}\,}
```

Actually the syntax is that of plain TeX and should be

```latex
\matrix{a & b \cr c & d }
```

Since you're essentially using `\matrix\def\\{b}...`, the argument to `\matrix` is `\def` and this breaks everything.

The `matrix` environment is defined by `amsmath`. If you change your code to

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix}
\def\\{b}
a \\ c
\end{matrix}\]
\end{document}
```

then you get what you want. But it's hard to know why. The redefinition of `\\` is just in the first cell of the matrix, so it won't propagate. If you do

```latex
\begin{matrix}
\def\\{b}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{matrix}
```

you'd get the standard meaning of `\\`.

Comment: Where does the `matrix` environment come from when not loading `amsmath`?

Comment: You're right; this is a foolish question, because the specific error I mention doesn't really have anything to do with my problem as I understood it.  Thank you.  Nonetheless, even with your fix, I don't understand why `\\ ` is only re-defined in the first cell.  Do `&` implicitly serve as group delimiters?

Comment: @wave The kernel defines `\matrix`. Because of how environments are implemented, `\begin{matrix}` eventually executes `\matrix`. In my opinion it has been done wrong from day one, but of course it's much too late to change it.

Comment: @LSpice Yes, they form implicit groups.

Comment: @egreg ah right, that's tricky. so one always has to use `\renewenvironment` if the name of the environment is a command that is already defined. never thought about it.

Comment: @egreg: Why is this wrong? This is just the Plain TeX version. What is the problem?

Comment: @user125730 The plain TeX version cannot be used in the environment form and needs `\cr` for ending rows.